# jQuery hover with animate then animate left in second handler issue?

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I can't seem to figure this small issue out. When I hover out of the div with class .nav_button the opacity changes but the moving of the button 15px up from the bottom doesn't seem to be taking effect in the second handler?

Js:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.nav_button').hover( 
    function(){
    $(this).animate({top:'15px',opacity:'0.5'},'slow')
    },
    function(){
    $(this).animate({bottom:'15px',opacity:'1'},'slow')
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.nav_button{
    height:80px;
    width:90px;
    margin-right:3px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid #555879;
    background-color:#2182c2;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;

}
```

Comment: show us your .nav_button css.

Comment: sorry i've edited it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/kNts8/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.nav_button').hover( 
    function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top:'-15px',opacity:'0.5'},'slow')
    },
    function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({top:'15px',opacity:'1'},'slow')
    });
});
```

## CSS

```
.nav_button{
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    padding:0 5px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy thank you!
Out of curiosity, why wouldn't 'bottom' work though ?

Comment: ya, I have to wait 4 minutes to accept :) 
So it's because it has a property of 15px top and and that needs to be changed in order for additional movement to take effect.

Comment: :) .animate() depends on its element css.